# Tried to parse chunked transfer encoding,it's not working though, the file which I decoded is totally unreadable

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio, chunked-encoding

I tried to parse the data which was generated by chunked transfer encoding in a Rest API ,I did see the data has value when I tried to print the value in a string and I thought it should be working,but when I tried to assign the value to the file, the file is totally unreadable, the code below I used boost library and I gonna elaborate my thoughts in the code , we gonna get started from the response portion of my code, I have no idea what wrong I have done

```
   // Send the request.
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    // Read the response status line. The response streambuf will automatically
    // grow to accommodate the entire line. The growth may be limited by passing
    // a maximum size to the streambuf constructor.
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
    {
        //std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
        return 9002;
         
    }
    if (status_code != 200)
    {
        //std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
        return 9003;
    }
    
    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Process the response headers.
    //this portion of code I tried to parse the file name in the header of response which the file name is in the  content-disposition of header
    std::string header;
    std::string fullHeader = "";
    string zipfilename="", txtfilename="";
    bool foundfilename = false;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
    {
        fullHeader.append(header).append("\n");
        std::transform(header.begin(), header.end(), header.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
        string containstr = "content-disposition";
        string containstr2 = "filename";
        string quotestr = "\"";
        if (header.find(containstr) != std::string::npos && header.find(containstr2) != std::string::npos)
        {
            int countquotes = 0;
            bool foundquote = true;
            
            std::size_t startpos = 0, beginpos, endpos;
            while (foundquote)
            {
                
                std::size_t myfound = header.find(quotestr, startpos);
                if (myfound != std::string::npos)
                {
                    if (countquotes % 2 == 0)
                        beginpos = myfound;
                    else
                    {
                        endpos = myfound;
                        foundfilename = true;
                    }

                    startpos = myfound + 1;
                    
                }
                else
                   foundquote = false;

                countquotes++;
            }

            if (endpos > beginpos && foundfilename)
            {
                size_t zipfileleng = endpos - beginpos;
                zipfilename = header.substr(beginpos+1, zipfileleng-1);
                txtfilename = header.substr(beginpos+1, zipfileleng-5);
            }
            else
                return 9004;

        }
    }

    if (foundfilename == false || zipfilename.length() == 0 || txtfilename.length() == 0)
        return 9005;

     //when the zipfilename has been found, we gonna get the data from the body of response, due to the response was  chunked transfer encoding, I tried to parse it,it's not complicated due to I saw it on the Wikipedia, it just first line was length of data,the next line was data,and it's the loop which over and over again ,all I tried to do was spliting all the data from the body of response by "\r\n" into a vector<string>, and I gonna read the data from that vector

      // Write whatever content we already have to output.
    std::string fullResponse = "";
    if (response.size() > 0)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << &response;
        fullResponse = ss.str();
     
    
    }
    //tried split the entire body of response into a vector<string>

     vector<string> allresponsedata;
    split_regex(allresponsedata, fullResponse, boost::regex("(\r\n)+"));
    
    //tried to merge the data of response
    string zipfiledata;
    int myindex = 0;
    for (auto &x : allresponsedata) {
        std::cout << "Split: " << x << std::endl;// I tried to print the data, I did see the value in the variable of x

        if (myindex % 2 != 0)
        {
            zipfiledata = zipfiledata + x;//tried to accumulate the datas
        }


        myindex++;
    }
    
    //tried to write the data into a file
    std::ofstream zipfilestream(zipfilename, ios::out | ios::binary);
    zipfilestream.write(zipfiledata.c_str(), zipfiledata.length());
    zipfilestream.close();

    //afterward, the zipfile was built, but it's unreadable which it's not able to open,the zip utlities software says it's a damaged zip file though
```

I even tried something else ways like this [slow http client based on boost::asio - (Chunked Transfer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780782/slow-http-client-based-on-boostasio-chunked-transfer)  ,but this way is not working as well ,VS says

```
  1 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::read" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket, boost::asio::streambuf, boost::asio::detail::transfer_exactly_t, std::error_code)
```

it just NOT able to compile in the line which is

```
size_t n = asio::read(socket, response, asio::transfer_exactly(chunk_bytes_to_read), error);
```

even I have read the example of asio::transfer_exactly, there's no exactly example like this though  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html

any idea?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't use [Boost Beast that supports chunked encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66756691/i-tried-to-download-a-file-with-boost-asio-but-it-doesnt-work-it-just-looks-l#comment118011473_66759719)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you read the format correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format

You need to read the chunk length (in hex) and any optional chunk extensions *before* accumulating the full response body.

It needs to be done before, because the sequence `\r\n` that you split on can easily appear inside the chunk data.

Again, I recommend to just use Beast's support, making it all a simple

```cpp
 http::response<http::string_body> response;
 boost::asio::streambuf buf;
 http::read(socket, buf, response);
```

And you will have the headers fully parsed, interpreted (including `Trailer`  headers!) and the content in `response.body()` as a `std::string`.

It will do the right thing even if the server doesn't use chunked encoding or combines with different encoding options.

There's simply no reason to reinvent the wheel.

### Full Demo

This demonstrates with the Chunked Encoding test url from https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    http::response<http::string_body> response;

    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::socket socket(ctx);

    connect(socket, tcp::resolver{ctx}.resolve("jigsaw.w3.org", "http"));

    http::write(
            socket,
            http::request<http::empty_body>(
                http::verb::get, "/HTTP/ChunkedScript", 11));

    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    http::read(socket, buf, response);

    std::cout << response.body() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Effective headers are:" << response.base() << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
This output will be chunked encoded by the server, if your client is HTTP/1.1
Below this line, is 1000 repeated lines of 0-9.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
...996 lines removed ...
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Effective headers are:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: max-age=0
date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 20:09:50 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: text/plain
etag: "1j3k6u8:tikt981g"
expires: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 20:09:49 GMT
last-modified: Mon, 18 Mar 2002 14:28:02 GMT
server: Jigsaw/2.3.0-beta3
```

Comment: Is "Beast" a typo or a library I've not heard of?

Comment: @BenVoigt You're missing out on a big thing: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html - Since boost 1.66.0 already!

Comment: I'm assuming that your example snippet needs some #includes not present in the question?

Comment: And (from Beast example code) also a `namespace http = beast::http;`  With that it becomes clear that the example actually uses Beast.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was taking a shortcut. I linked a complete example from the comment at an earlier answer. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889515/tried-to-parse-chunked-transfer-encoding-its-not-working-though-the-file-which/66891423?noredirect=1#comment118241386_66889515)).  Really, how to do it with Beast in no wau answers the question here, so it's a by-line here.

Comment: @BenVoigt That said, it wasn't too hard once I found a suitable [online test page](https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/) to use. Added

Comment: @sehe hi there, I really appeciate it

Comment: @Ken Does that mean you'll be using Beast? If so, what should I have said differently the other time to make you consider that? It seems that would have saved a lot of time.

Comment: @sehe I have used the beast, it works, thank you so much